# Unhandle rejection promise async await chain

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm fairly new to async await in javascript so this question might be something I don't know.

I have this

```
  async function foo(req, res, next) {
    try {
      await scan(req.params.stack);
      res.send('ok');
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send('fail');
    }
  }

async function scan(stack) {
  try {
    const libs = [1,2,3];
    const promises = libs.map(async l => analyze(stack, l)
      .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); }));
    return q.allSettled(promises)
      .then((results) => {
        const rejected = results.filter(r => r.state === 'rejected');
        if (rejected.length === results.length) throw new Error('Failed');
        return results;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

async function analyze(stack, libraries) {
  try {
    const config = await buildConfiguration(stack, libraries);
    return await databaseInsertion(vulnsObject);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject('Error while trying to analyze libs');
  }
}
```

Somehow I'm getting this wild warning and I don't know where I am not catching the error.

Of course, I'm making build configuration fail in order to test the error, but instead of having a normal flow cathing the error I got this:

```
(node:415) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Error while trying to analyze libs
```

Am I using async await good? Is there any pattern I should follow in order to chain async await?

The wild thing is that the foo function works well, meaning that the res.status.(500).send('fail'); works and I'm getting the response

When I was using native promises this error didn't appear.

I'm really stuck here

Comment: If you are calling `analyze` function to start it all, then remember that calling `async` function will return a promise. And, you must attach `catch` to a promise, otherwise you will get a warning (in case of rejection). Log the error in the third last line to see the error.

Comment: I know it, but  I think the 'catchs' are good, but it seems that at least i need one more, but i dont know where.

Comment: `analyze(stack, libs).catch(err => console.error(err))`, assuming you are calling `analyze` function.

Comment: take a closer look to the function please, it's already there

Comment: Okay, let me explain in my answer, its difficult to explain this in comments

Comment: Just do `throw new Error('Error while trying to analyze libs');` inside analyze catch.

Comment: It's the same that return promise.reject

Answer (score 4):

While using `async-await` scan function you were mixing `.then()` `.catch()` waterfall with `await`. `async-await` handles promises as good as `.then()`. So stick with one flow and try to mix both in one function or one inside another.

```
async foo(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await scan(req.params.stack);
        res.send('ok');
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send('fail');
    }
}

async scan(stack) {
  try {
    const libs = [1,2,3];

    // This libs.map functions return promise. then why not use await?
    const promises = await libs.map(async l => analyze(stack, l);

    // Again q.allSettled returns promise, use await here too
    let results = await q.allSettled(promises);

    const rejected = results.filter(r => r.state === 'rejected');

    if (rejected.length === results.length) throw new Error('Failed');

    return results;

  }

  // If any promise call reject function will be in catch
  catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

async function analyze(stack, libraries) {
    try {
        const config = await buildConfiguration(stack, libraries);
        return await databaseInsertion(vulnsObject);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem, the thing doing this is that the rejected array now it's empty and i shouldn't be

Answer (score 1):

Calling an `async` function (here, `analyze`) would return a promise, which will resolve or reject according to the return value of the `async` function or whether an error was thrown.

Now, the `analyze` function is handling the error thrown but it will return a `Promise.reject()` when an error is thrown. A `Promise.reject()` is the unhandled rejection here, which is what the log is stating.

In terms of a synchronous function the equivalent will be

```
function sync() {
  try {
    // do something dangerous
  } catch (ex) {
    throw Error('Something bad happened'); // this error is still being thrown and nobody is handling it
  }
}
```

To handle this error you can do the following when you are calling sync, wrap it in try and catch again

```
try {
  sync();
} catch (ex) {
  console.error(ex); // not gonna throw another exception, otherwise the program might crash
}
```

Now, the equivalent of this wrap for the `analyze` function will be using another async function, or better since calling `async` function will return a `Promise`, use the `catch` method of a `Promise`

```
analyze()
  .then(() => console.log('My work is done here'))
  .catch(ex => console.error(ex)); // NOTE: not throwing another exception
```

Even better would be to not return a rejection from `catch` in the first place, thus making `analyze`,

```
async function analyze(stack, libraries) {
  try {
    const config = await buildConfiguration(stack, libraries);
    return await databaseInsertion(vulnsObject);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err); // not eating up good errors with something vague is always good
    return null; // or something else to signify that insert failed
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the "NOTE" tag, that's what you mean. I will try! thank you!

Comment: The thing here is that if a don't throw any error where u tagged the "NOTE", the rejected array is always empty. Meaning, no rejection is rejected.

Comment: Any other idea !?

Answer (score 0):

In the analyze() you are returning Project.reject() but analyze() is an async function. Therefor it resolves any value that you return and rejects any error you throw.

```
    async function analyze(stack, libraries) {
        try {
            const config = await buildConfiguration(stack, libraries);
            return await databaseInsertion(vulnsObject);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject('Error while trying to analyze libs');
        }
    }
```

So when the analyze function catches an error you are creating a rejection but then resolving the function. So `Promise.reject('Error while trying to analyze libs');` is not being handled. Since async functions always return a promise that resolves with whatever you return and rejects whatever you throw, your analyze function is always going to resolve. Try doin this...

```
    async function analyze(stack, libraries) {
        try {
            const config = await buildConfiguration(stack, libraries);
            return await databaseInsertion(vulnsObject);
        } catch (err) {
            throw Error('Error while trying to analyze libs');
        }
    }
```

The other thing I see as a possible problem in this code is even though you pass the `map(async func)` an async function, it doesn't care. It won't wait for each function to complete before calling the next.

```
const promises = libs.map(async l => analyze(stack, l)
      .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); }));
    return q.allSettled(promises)
      .then((results) => {
        const rejected = results.filter(r => r.state === 'rejected');
        if (rejected.length === results.length) throw new Error('Failed');
        return results;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
```

There are two changes bellow

```
const promises = libs.map(async l => await analyze(stack, l)
      .catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); }));
    return q.allSettled( await promises)
      .then((results) => {
        const rejected = results.filter(r => r.state === 'rejected');
        if (rejected.length === results.length) throw new Error('Failed');
        return results;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
```

I added an await before the analyze function and an await before passing the promises variable into `q.allSettled()`.